# Comparing by value in multiple lists with lambda functions

Tags: java, android, guava

I am stuck on the comparison of the 2 or more same size lists according to values. Some background: I am trying to make a racing app that tracks your laps through sectors, and then provides the ideal line, which is the lowest time recorded at sector. The data is put in hashmap, the key being lap and values being the array of floats. So far I have tried doing it like this (under the code it's the data in provided format). I'd like to know if it is possible to compare the values in the array by position (e.g. first position with first position in other arrays, second position with second position in other arrays etc.), since mine is flawed - via the Guava functions, or any other better way of comparing. Thank you for your help.

```
public ArrayList<Float> idealLine(Map<Integer, List<Float>> durations) {
    
   ArrayList<Float> idealLap = new ArrayList<Float>();
   
    for(int i = 0; i < durations.size(); i++) {
        if(durations.size() < (i + 1)) {
            break;
        }
        else {

            ArrayList<Float> values = new ArrayList<Float>();
            for(int key : durations.keySet()) {
                values.add(durations.get(key).get(i));
            }

            int index = values.indexOf(Collections.min(values));

            idealLap.add(values.get(index));
        }
    }
    return idealLap;
}

//        1/[18.0, 18.0, 13.0, 5.0, 18.0]
//        2/[18.0, 18.0, 13.0, 5.0, 18.0]
//        3/[19.0, 27.0, 22.0, 8.0, 31.0]
//        4/[21.0, 22.0, 15.0, 6.0, 21.0]
```

Preferred output I desire is the lowest value from each column, so i.e. 18.0, 18.0, 13.0, 5.0, 18.0.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify which result of the comparison do you expect (probably providing a failing test case).

Comment: Hello, and thank you. My expected result is to get the lowest value from each column, so that it should be like this: 18.0, 18.0, 13.0, 5.0, 18.0. Currently, I have done it as shown above, which only provides as much values as there is laps, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As [tweeted by StackOverflow's creator, Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096), you made one of most commons errors in programming: off-by-one when iterating. Once you change your loop to non-strict inequality `for(int i = 0; i <= durations.size(); i++)` and remove superfluous if condition, you'll be good.

```
@Test
public void shouldPrintIdealLineMap() {
    final ArrayList<Float> idealLine = idealLine(Map.of(
            1, List.of(18.0f, 18.0f, 13.0f, 5.0f, 18.0f),
            2, List.of(18.0f, 18.0f, 13.0f, 5.0f, 18.0f),
            3, List.of(19.0f, 27.0f, 22.0f, 8.0f, 31.0f),
            4, List.of(21.0f, 22.0f, 15.0f, 6.0f, 21.0f)
    ));
    assertThat(idealLine)
            .containsExactly(18.0f, 18.0f, 13.0f, 5.0f, 18.0f);
}

public static ArrayList<Float> idealLine(Map<Integer, List<Float>> durations) {

    ArrayList<Float> idealLap = new ArrayList<Float>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= durations.size(); i++) {

        ArrayList<Float> values = new ArrayList<Float>();
        for (int key : durations.keySet()) {
            values.add(durations.get(key).get(i));
        }

        int index = values.indexOf(Collections.min(values));

        idealLap.add(values.get(index));
    }
    return idealLap;
}
```